# SQL skips first value of select

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am unsure why my code is omitting the first row received on a select statement. The code is:

```
func (s *sqlserver) FindAllProducts() (products []*Product, err error) {
    ctx, cancel := getContext()
    defer cancel()

    rows, err := s.QueryContext(ctx,
        "select productid, productname, pricecents, brandname from products")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }   
    defer rows.Close()
    
    for rows.Next() {
        product := new(Product)
        err = rows.Scan(
            &product.ProductID,
            &product.ProductName,
            &product.PriceCents,
            &product.BrandName,
            )
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        products = append(products, product)
    }
    return
}
```

and there is a unit test, which uses `go-sqlmock` to serve a test repo:

```
func TestProduct(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        require.NoError(t, err)
    }
    s := sqlserver{db}
    defer s.Close()

    product1 := &Product{
        1,
        "soda",
        100,
        "prites",
    }
    product2 := &Product{
        60,
        "slurpee",
        400,
        "koce",
    }
    product3 := &Product{
        21,
        "borg",
        210,
        "ham",
    }

    query := "^insert into *"
    mock.ExpectExec(query).
        WithArgs(product1.ProductID, product1.ProductName, product1.PriceCents, product1.BrandName).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(0, 1))

    query = "^insert into *"
    mock.ExpectExec(query).
        WithArgs(product2.ProductID, product2.ProductName, product2.PriceCents, product2.BrandName).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))

    query = "^insert into *"
    mock.ExpectExec(query).
        WithArgs(product3.ProductID, product3.ProductName, product3.PriceCents, product3.BrandName).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(2, 1))

    query = "^select .+ from *"
    rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"productid", "productname", "pricecents", "brandname"}).
        AddRow(product1.ProductID, product1.ProductName, product1.PriceCents, product1.BrandName)
    mock.ExpectQuery(query).
        WithArgs(product1.ProductID).
        WillReturnRows(rows)

    query = "^select .+ from *"
    rows.AddRow(product2.ProductID, product2.ProductName, product2.PriceCents, product2.BrandName)
    rows.AddRow(product3.ProductID, product3.ProductName, product3.PriceCents, product3.BrandName)
    mock.ExpectQuery(query).
        WillReturnRows(rows)

    err = s.InsertProduct(product1)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    err = s.InsertProduct(product2)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    err = s.InsertProduct(product3)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    product, err := s.FindProductFromID(product1.ProductID)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, product1, product)

    products, err := s.FindAllProducts()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Len(t, products, 3)
    assert.Equal(t, *product1, *products[0])
    assert.Equal(t, *product2, *products[1])
    assert.Equal(t, *product3, *products[2])

    err = mock.ExpectationsWereMet()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

Inserting products into the table works fine, but when I try to retrieve the products using `s.FindAllProducts` the first product is always missing from the returned products (causing `assert.Len(t, products, 3)` to fail). Any help much appreciated!

Edit: Regarding calling `rows.Next()` before scanning the values into the product, this is what the documentation says to do, as the pointer is supposed to start one index before the first row. However, I have debugged the code and the problem seems to be that the pointer is starting one place ahead (pointing to the first row) and calling `rows.Next()` moves it to the next row. I have tried moving this statement after initializing the product but the code then throws the error:
`Received unexpected error: sql: Scan called without calling Next`

Edit 2: This seems to be a direct problem with `go-sqlmock`, as after testing on a real SQL database the database correctly returns all 3 rows.

Comment: Please clarify where exactly your test fails? Is `assert.Len(t, products, 3)`  failing because threre is only 2 products?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Golang, but my guess is that calling `rows.Next()` moves pointer to the second row. Try instantiating Product first and calling `rows.Next()` as last thing in the loop.

Comment: Note that you must do your error checking _before_ `defer rows.Close()`. Otherwise an error will cause your program to panic, becuase `rows` will be nil.

Comment: Also note that your regex `"^insert into *"` almost certainly does not mean what you intend.  It means "A string that starts with `insert into`, followed by 0 or more spaces" :) This means that `insert intolerant` would match, as would `insert into                             wheee!` You probably meant `"^insert into .*"`, which can be shortened to: `^insert into "`

Comment: Why do you have `()` in your SELECT?, Please remove them to get results.

Comment: 1. Yes, `assert.Len` is failing because it is only returning the last two products.

Comment: 2. I am aware of other inconsistencies with my code, such as the lack of error checking and the regex statements (thanks for pointing those out!) but my main issue is stemming from the select only returning two products instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, as rows is a pointer for some reason `go-sqlmock` modifies the rows set, causing the original rows in it to be removed and requiring a reset each time `WillReturnRows` is called. The following portion of the code:

```
    query = "^select .+ from *"
    rows.AddRow(product2.ProductID, product2.ProductName, product2.PriceCents, product2.BrandName)
    rows.AddRow(product3.ProductID, product3.ProductName, product3.PriceCents, product3.BrandName)
    mock.ExpectQuery(query).
        WillReturnRows(rows)
```

should be modified to add the original row back, like so:

```
    query = "^select .+ from *"
    rows = sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"productid", "productname", "pricecents", "brandname"})
    rows.AddRow(product1.ProductID, product1.ProductName, product1.PriceCents, product2.BrandName)
    rows.AddRow(product2.ProductID, product2.ProductName, product2.PriceCents, product2.BrandName)
    rows.AddRow(product3.ProductID, product3.ProductName, product3.PriceCents, product3.BrandName)
    mock.ExpectQuery(query).
        WillReturnRows(rows)
```

and the test now passes!